# Speed up a MongoDB find() with better sorting? (using mongoose orm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database, nosql

Right now I have something like this....

```
Item.find({}, function (docs) {
    for (var i = docs.length-15; i < docs.length; i++){
     client.send(JSON.stringify(docs[i]));
    }                   
});
```

but it seems to be very slow. I'm hoping to speed it up by doing something like...

```
Item.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(15)...?
```

Is this possible? Will it help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gleam from the [actual source code and tests](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/test/model.querying.test.js), since mongoose **1.0.14** the *sort()* parameter has changed slightly to no longer accept an array. Furthermore, you seem to need to call *find()* again on the actual Query object which is returned on the find call (plus watching out for your err object). So:-

```
  Item.find().sort('_id','descending').limit(15).find(function(err, doc) {
    client.send(JSON.stringify(doc));
  });
```

Hopefully might do what you need.

Comment: thanks man. For some reason what you have there didn't work but a slight tweak back to each did it for me! `Item.find().sort('_id','descending').limit(15).each(function(err, doc) {client.send(JSON.stringify(doc));});` that silly mongoose... thanks again man

Comment: Also of note, for some reason it seems to always return an extra doc that is just `null`. So you might need if(doc != null){} or something depending on what your doing with the data.

Comment: Yeah, christ knows cause If I don't use the find() call and use each() instead, I just get the one { doc: } object instead of an array of them. I'm using mongoose 1.2.0 here though. Anyway, glad it helped a bit. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are only interested in the first (or last as in the case of sorting with `_id: -1`) 15 documents then yes, setting a limit on the query is a very good idea. Limiting on the client side as in your first example means that the database sends every single document to the client, and then the client ignores every but the last 15.

However, the Mongoose syntax for specifying a limit is different from the Mongo shell syntax, here what I think you want:

```
Item.find().sort([['_id','descending']]).limit(15).each(function(doc) {
  client.send(JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```

If I'm not mistaken you can chain a number of actions on a Mongoose query, and then call `each` to send it and get each document of the result passed to your callback.

Comment: @Theo I get this error:

`Error: Error: Illegal sort clause, must be of the form [['field1', '(ascending|descending)'], ['field2', '(ascending|descending)']]\n `

Comment: Hm, perhaps there was one level of arrays too many, try `.sort(['_id','descending'])` (notice there are only one level of square brackets). I've updated the answer too.

Comment: You're missing the closing paren on client.send, no?

Comment: @Theo, hrrm not sure what's going on, it still results in the same error.

Comment: According to everything I've been able to find through Google `sort([['_id','descending']])` is the right syntax (it was right from the start). The Mongoose docs are atrocious. Sorry, but I have no idea why it doesn't work. Even the error message doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I feel your pain float/Theo, I've been googling for the past hour or so just working out how to sort properly.